# React Native and iOS share button

Tags: ios, react-native, share-button

I am trying to access iOS' share button where you can share content to all services, including messages etc...
Any idea how I could do this? Thanks

Comment: The "iOS share button" is UIActivityViewController: http://jairtrejo.mx/blog/2015/09/share-button-react-native

Comment: Ok thanks so I would have to write it in ObjC and then link it @IanBell?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/RCTActionSheetManager.m

Answer (score 7):

You now have a simple Share API in react-native.

```
import { Share } from "react-native"

Share.share(
      {
        title: "a title",
        message: "some message",
        // or
        url: imageReference
      },
      (options)
    );
```

See http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share.html

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this out of the box in React Native - just use `ActionSheetIOS.showShareActionSheetWithOptions`. See the documentation [here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/actionsheetios.html#showshareactionsheetwithoptions).

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out the [react-native-share](https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share) package, it should cover your usecase. You can also see more relevant packages on [JS.Coach](https://js.coach/react-native?search=share)

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier than you think. Adding to @MoOx answer further.

With the new share api available, you can easily share information with your React Native app by just using it with all variables and configuration. ([see here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/share))

```
import React from 'react';
import { Share, View, Button } from 'react-native';

const ShareExample = () => {
  const onShare = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await Share.share({
        message:
          'React Native | A framework for building native apps using React',
      });
      if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
        if (result.activityType) {
          // shared with activity type of result.activityType
        } else {
          // shared
        }
      } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
        // dismissed
      }
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  };
  return (
    <View style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>
      <Button onPress={onShare} title="Share" />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ShareExample;
```